# ¿Cómo definir clases respetando el encapsulamiento en Dart?

Tags: poo, flutter, dart

He visto que en todos los tutoriales (incluso en la documentación oficial) se definen las clases de esta forma:

```
class Point {
  final double x;
  final double y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);
}
```

Sin embargo, definiendo así la clase hacemos accesibles las variables `x` e `y` fuera de la clase `Point`. Esto viola el [principio de encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)). Para solucionar esto suelo utilizar la siguiente forma para definir clases:

```
class Point {
  final double _x;
  final double _y;

  Point(x, y): this._x = x, this._y = y;
}
```

Haciendo así las variables privadas. Aun así, en todos los proyectos y documentación que leí sobre flutter no vi que nadie defina las variables de esta forma u parecida. Hay alguna razón por la que no se respete el principio de encapsulamiento en dart? O hay alguna otra forma de definir las variables del constructor utilizando mejores prácticas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El encapsulamiento no necesariamente se refiere a ocultar las propiedades de una clase, también puede ser que se restringen accesos, es decir, podríamos restringir la modificación de esas propiedades, que es lo que se hace al definir:

```
class Point {
  final double x;
  final double y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);
}
```

Podemos acceder a los elementos del objeto, más no podemos modificarlo.
He visto algunos Widgets en Flutter en el que sí ocultan atributos, y lo hacen con un propósito específico, NO quieren que los devs accedan a estos, pero en el caso de tu clase `Point`, podrías hacerlo como mencionas:

```dart
class Point {
  final double _x;
  final double _y;

  Point(x, y): this._x = x, this._y = y;
}
```

Pero, tendría sentido? Sí y solo sí, no quieres que desde otro archivo accedan a las propiedades del objeto Point, de lo contrario, está bien definirlo como la primera forma.

En conclusión, ambas formas son correctas de acuerdo a lo que requieras.

Lo que sí, estaría mal (si no quieres tener un objeto inmutable), sería definir la clase así (sin el modificador final):

```dart
class Point {
  double x;
  double y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);
}
```

Ya que se podría modificar las propiedades del objeto Point una vez definido.

```dart
final punto = Point(4,5);
punto.x = 3;
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, te agradezco